# spark save and read parquet on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

I am writing this code

```
val inputData = spark.read.parquet(inputFile)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",6)
val outputData = inputData.sort($"colname")
outputData.write.parquet(outputFile) //write on HDFS
```

If I want to read the content of the file "outputFile" from HDFS, I don't find the same number of partitions and the data is not sorted. Is this normal?

I am using Spark 2.0

Comment: How are you checking the number of partitions and reading the content of the file? Do you use `show()` or `take()` to display the contents?

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate deficiency of Spark.  While `write.parquet` saves files as `part-00000.parquet`, `part-00001.parquet`, ... , it saves no partition information, and does not guarantee that `part-00000` on disk is read back as the first partition.

We have added functionality for our project to a) read back partitions in the same order (this involves doing some somewhat-unsafe partition casting and sorting based on the contained filename), and b) serialize partitioners to disk and read them back.

As far as I know, there is nothing you can do in stock Spark at the moment to solve this problem.  I look forward to seeing a resolution in future versions of Spark!

Edit: My experience is in Spark 1.5.x and 1.6.x.  If there is a way to do this in native Spark with 2.0, please let me know!

Answer (score -4):

You should make use of the `repartition()` instead. This would write the parquet file the way you want it:

```
outputData.repartition(6).write.parquet("outputFile")
```

Then, it would be the same if you try to read it back .

Parquet preserves the order of rows. You should use `take()` instead of `show()` to check the contents. `take(n)` returns the first `n` rows and the way it works is by first reading the first partition to get an idea of the partition size and then getting the rest of the data in batches..

Comment: How does it help if OP want globally sorted output?

Comment: The OP is interested in reading back with the same partitioning.  This answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the OP's question.